# Truncate the result to to two decimal places and round them up to the next whole percent in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In this below code I get a certain percent as a result.

```
    RatioPercent = case 
        when input.Name = 'Abc' then convert(int, lbase.AbcRatio)
        end,
```

I want the RatioPercent to be truncated (shortened) to two decimal places and the truncated result must be rounded up to the next whole percent.

For example: `96.001%` will be delivered as `96` and `80.01%` will be delivered as `81`.

If I use `cast()` then it will just give me `96` and `80`.

```
    RatioPercent = case 
        when input.Name = 'Abc' then cast(convert(int, lbase.AbcRatio) as decimal (10, 0))
        end,
```

But if I use `ceiling()` instead of `cast()` then it will give me 97 and 81.

Comment: what happens if it's 77.02%? will this be 79?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu if it is 77.02 it will be 78. Anything that is 77.01 or above should be rounded to the next whole number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine `ceiling` and `cast` together, first casting to 2 decimal places, and then rounding up:

```
select ceiling(cast(96.001 as decimal(10,2)))
union all 
select ceiling(cast(80.01 as decimal(10,2)))
```

Results in 96 and 81.

- [Online Demo](https://rextester.com/ESUY37393)

---

Edit, in regards to the comment by  Jeroen Mostert, if you need 96.009 to round down to 96, here's an alternative option using `round`:

```
select ceiling(round(96.009, 2, 1))
```

Comment: This gives `97` for the input `96.009`. `CAST` rounds, it does not truncate.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Updated the answer to use `round` if that's what the OP needs -- good catch, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
select ceiling(cast(96.001 * 100 as int) /100.0)
union all
select ceiling(cast(80.01 * 100 as int) /100.0)
```

Results are `96` and `81`

**Update**

Ran some tests on a table with about 50,000 rows, and the current accepted answer (`ceiling(cast(96.001 as decimal(10,2)))`) ran 3ms faster... so stick with that.

Here's a quick test with several options you can plug into a table on your own database:

```
set statistics time on

--uncomment exactly one line below
 --select [column]  --control
 --select ceiling(([column] * 100) /100.0) 
 --select ceiling(cast([column] as decimal(10,2))) 
 --select ceiling(floor([column] * 100 )/100)

from [Table]
set statistics time off
```

Comment: How about `CEILING(FLOOR(96.001 * 100) / 100)`? Not sure what the `int` casts are supposed to accomplish.

Comment: You have to cast at some point, because a decimal multiplied or divided by an int is still a decimal, and they want an int result.

Comment: Well yes, but the type of your expression is still `numeric` as well, so... As long as the end result has no decimals (zero scale) I'd just leave it up to the final assignment/conversion.

Comment: I just checked, and the accepted answer was still slightly faster, though it was closer.

Comment: It may be faster, but it doesn't give the same results -- and it doesn't give the *right* results, if I read the question correctly, but only the OP could confirm that. Performance before correctness and all that (and that's assuming performance is even relevant here -- usually this kind of percentage hoopla isn't run over thousands of rows and even if it is it's not the bottleneck in the query, but YMMV).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a combination of `cast` with 2 decimals, then `ceiling` :

```
ceiling(cast(convert(int, lbase.AbcRatio) as decimal (10, 2))
```